# UITableView - How to stop weird animation on header views?

Tags: ios7, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I have a table view with multiple sections that are collapsable, i.e. on touch on the section it expands & collapses the cells that they have with

```
 - (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

&

```
- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

respectively.

The issue is that when I'm collapsing the cells, the header views below them that are needed to be redrawn are shrinked with a weird expanding animation.

Why is this header view animation happening, how to control it, is there any way to remove it?

[image]

[image]

The app is targeted for iOS7 & above, so I couldn't know if that's an iOS 7 only issue, since they made some changes in rendering the UITableView too.